# Regex to match ERROR or INFO, but with different actions depending on the match

Tags: python, regex

I am iterating through a log file to list how many ERROR messages and INFO messages each user has generated. I am trying to do it in one regex pattern and add the captured line to a different list depending on if the line is an ERROR or an INFO messages.
The contents of the log file look like this:

> Jan 31 00:21:30 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR The ticket was modified while updating (john123)
>
> Jan 31 00:44:34 ubuntu.local ticky: INFO Closed ticket [#1754] (jack456)

Comment: You don't need a regex for this: `if 'INFO' in line: info_list.append(line);`  etc.

Comment: Controlling program logic is not in the domain of regular expressions. They match things, but they don't decide what to do with what they matched.

Comment: This is only one part of a larger project that I am doing for an online course that requires the use of regular expressions. But your explanation still helped, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I want to point out that it would likely be far easier to do this with simple if statements, checking if the substrings are in the log line

```py
for line in log_contents:
    if "ERROR" in line:
        # do error actions
    elif "INFO" in line:
        # do info actions
```

If you are determined to use regex something like this should work, and I'd suggeting looking at the docs for the [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) python package for more info on useing regex in python:

```py
import re

# read log file into `log_contents`

pattern = re.compile("(ERROR|INFO)")

for line in log_contents:
    match = pattern.search(line)
    if match is not None:
        if match.group(0) == "Error":
            # do error actions
        elif match.group(0) == "INFO":
            # do info actions
```